# SQL - Combine Multiple Rows of Data to One Row and Column

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

I'm looking to create a SQL Server query that will combine resources with the same Task into one row/record string using three tables. My SQL Server query below doesn't seem to be working correctly and takes a very long time to execute and then errors out. Thanks!

**Task Table**

```
TaskUID
TaskName
```

**Assignment Table**

```
TaskUID
ResourceUID
```

**Resource Table**

```
ResourceUID
ResourceName
```

**Before**

```
**Task Name     Resource Name**
Weapon Launch   Amy
Weapon Launch   Sam
Weapon Launch   Marisa
Weapon Launch   Katy
Weapon Launch   John
Sweating Tears  Marisa
Sweating Tears  Joe
Sweating Tears  Katy
Sweating Tears  Michael
Ramp Diver      Joe
Ramp Diver      Michael
```

**After**

```
**Task Name     Resource Name**
Weapon Launch   Amy; Sam; Marisa; Katy; John
Sweating Tears  Marisa; Joe; Katy; Michael
Ramp Diver      Michael; Joe
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T.TaskName,
STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + R.RESOURCENAME
FROM 
[Resource Table] R
LEFT JOIN [Assignment Table] A ON R.ResourceUID=A.ResourceUID
WHERE
A.TASKUID=T.TaskUID
Group by R.RESOURCENAME
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'') Resources
FROM [Task Table] T
INNER JOIN [Assignment Table] A ON T.TASKUID=A.TASKUID
```

Comment: Bring back three result sets and squish them together yourself. That's the easiest way.

Comment: See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) for how to do this.

Comment: You can create an aggregate function using assembly.

Comment: Do you have indexes in your tables? It makes a lot of difference. I believe the IDs are indexes for Resource and Task tables. What about the [Assignment Table]? (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4efb8/1)

Comment: No, we don't have indexes in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT T.TaskName, Resources
FROM TaskTable T
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 
    STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + R.RESOURCENAME
      FROM [ResourceTable] R
      INNER JOIN [AssignmentTable] A ON R.ResourceUID=A.ResourceUID
      WHERE A.TASKUID = T.TASKUID
      Group by R.RESOURCENAME
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'') Resources
) N(Resources)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdd19/24)

Comment: Nizam, I've tried and it was running over 15 minutes to execute. My [TaskTable] has about 40,000 records. I think it would eventually complete but it would take quite a bit of time to run. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What about your Resource Table?

Comment: About 900 records in the [ResourceTable].

Comment: I've never done assemblies before and I'm pretty new to SQL server. Also not sure if special permission is needed to do assemblies in my environment either.

Comment: Look my above comment. It is pretty easy to create aggregate functions. I have package a DLL to do this. I think it worth a try.

Comment: I don't have the permissions to do assemblies.

Comment: Then your best bet is create indexes (if they dont exist already)

Comment: They don't exist already and I don't have the permissions to do indexes. I appreciate your help. The SQL Project Server does not have any built in indexes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nizam, I figured out that I should be using the tables in the database instead of views, since I do not have permissions to create indexes. The built-in indexes allowed for faster queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
T.TASK_NAME,
    STUFF((SELECT ', '+ R.RES_NAME
            FROM PUB.MSP_RESOURCES R
            JOIN PUB.MSP_ASSIGNMENTS A ON A.RES_UID=R.RES_UID
            WHERE A.TASK_UID=T.TASK_UID
            AND R.RES_TYPE IN(2)
            GROUP BY R.RES_NAME
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS RESOURCES
```